# TIKZ Tree: Change angle between Nodes

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-angles

I am struggling to find out how to change the angle between nodes in tikz trees. I have already tried the attribute `sibling angle=...` specifically for child nodes or as `level 1/.style=...` attribute at the beginning of the \tikzpicture environment. `Sibling distance` works for me, but `Sibling angle` does not change anything. Look at the following example:

What I want is that the angle between B and C gets wider or narrower. I need that for a bigger tree where there is a lot of overlapping.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

%------------------ Tikz Settings----------------------------    
% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]

%Define tree diagram styles   
\tikzstyle{Decision} = [shape=rectangle,
                        draw,
                        double=black,
                        double distance=1pt,
                        text=black]
\tikzstyle{Lottery} = [shape=circle,
                        draw,
                        double=black,
                        double distance=1pt,
                        text=black]
\tikzstyle{Outcome}     = [circle,
                       minimum width=3pt,
                       fill, 
                       inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}   
        \begin{figure}
                \centering                  
                \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped, scale=0.7,level 1/.style={sibling angle=60, sibling distance=60mm}]         
                \node [Decision,label=left:{}] {A}
                [node distance = 100mm]
                child[sibling angle=10]{ 
                    node[Decision,label=right:{}] {B}
                        edge from parent
                        node[above] {}
                    }
                child{ 
                    node[Decision,label=right:{}] {C}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {}
                };      
                \end{tikzpicture}                       
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From TikZ manual follows: `/tikz/sibling angle=<angle>` **Sets the angle between siblings in the grow cyclic style.** Since you not declare `grow cyclic`, this option has no influence on tree.

Comment: **forest** has something like this. But with **forest** you probably wouldn't need to set it manually anyway. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated by the way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to use **forest**, you can specify the angles between the siblings and their parent nodes etc. in various ways. Note, however, that **forest** is pretty good at auto-adjusting these kinds of things, so you may not really need to set them manually.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  Decision/.style = {%
    draw,
    line width=1.4pt
  },
  Lottery/.style = {%
    draw,
    line width=1.4pt
  },
  Outcome/.style = {%
    circle,
    minimum width=3pt,
    fill,
    inner sep=0pt
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow=0,
    Decision,
    calign angle=60,
    calign=fixed edge angles,
  }
  [A
    [B, calign secondary angle=80, calign primary angle=-60
      [D]
      [E]
    ]
    [C, calign secondary angle=70, calign primary angle=-60
      [F]
      [G]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: angles in trees]